# C Queue with arrays as entries

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, queue

I'm trying to use a Queue as a buffer for failed messages via LTE-M.  So that if there is a connection again i can send all the failed messages out of the buffer.

For that i created two files.

1. queue_array.h

```
#ifndef INC_QUEUE_ARRAY_H_
#define INC_QUEUE_ARRAY_H_

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define QUEUE_EMPTY 0

/*Queue has five properties. capacity stands for the maximum number of elements Queue can hold.
  Size stands for the current size of the Queue and elements is the array of elements. front is the
 index of first element (the index at which we remove the element) and rear is the index of last element
 (the index at which we insert the element) */
typedef struct
{
    int head, tail, num_entries, size;
    char **values;
}queue;


void init_queue(queue *q, int max_size);
bool queue_empty(queue *q);
bool queue_full(queue *q);
void queue_destroy(queue *q);
bool enqueue(queue *q , char *element);
int dequeue(queue *q);
int count_queue(queue *q);
char* front(queue *q);


#endif /* INC_QUEUE_ARRAY_H_ */
```

2. Queue_array.c

```
#include "queue_array.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


void init_queue(queue *q, int max_size)
{
    q->size=max_size;
    q->values=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*q->size);
    q->num_entries =0; //empty
    q->head=0;
    q->tail=0;
}

bool queue_empty(queue*q)
{
    return(q->num_entries ==0);
}

bool queue_full(queue*q)
{
    return(q->num_entries == q->size);
}

void queue_destroy(queue*q)
{
    free(q->values);
}

int dequeue(queue *q)
{
    if(queue_empty(q))
        {
            return QUEUE_EMPTY;
        }
    q->head = (q->head +1) % q->size;
    q->num_entries--;

   return 1;
}

char* front(queue *q)
{
        if(q->size!=0)
        {
                /* Return the element which is at the front*/
                return q->values[q->head];
        }
        return NULL;
}

int count_queue(queue *q)
{
    return q->num_entries;
}

bool enqueue(queue *q , char *element)
{
    if(queue_full(q))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        q->num_entries++;
        q->tail=(q->tail +1) % q->size;
        q->values[q->tail] = (char *) malloc((sizeof(element)+1)* sizeof(char));
        strcpy(q->values[q->tail], element);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Now when i run this code i only have these chars in the front element: "MESSAGE". Because there is something of the message there i think the mistake is in the enqueue function where the storage  of the q->value is allocated.. But i dont know where. Does someone see the mistake?

Run Code:

```
char *temp;
init_queue(&msg_queue, 5);
if(enqueue(&msg_queue,"FIRSTFAILEDTEXTMESSAGE")!=0)
{
//nothing
}
if(enqueue(&msg_queue,"SECONDFAILEDTEXTMESSAGE")!=0)
{
//nothing
}
temp= front(&msg_queue);
temp = (char *)malloc(22 * sizeof(char )); //allocate the first message with 22 Chars
```

Comment: `malloc((sizeof(element)+1)`... That's not how you determine the length of a string in C. Try using `strlen( element) +1` as the number of bytes needed from `malloc()`...

Comment: Thank you for your reply. After changing the sizeof to strlen i dont see "MESSAGE" any more in the front element. So there has to be another problem..

Comment: When the queue starts empty, and an item is added, the code increments the tail, but the head is still referencing an empty node... That first item "pushed" onto an empty list (head == tail) doesn't need to have any pre-increment.